# Почему не работает код скачивания картинки?

Tags: php, мойсклад-api

Несколько недель назад сделал скачивание картинок с МоегоСклада и всё нормально работало.

приведу код функций для скачивания:

```
public function saveImgMoySklad($imgUrl, $pathSave, $username, $password) {

    $auth = base64_encode("{$username}:{$password}");
    $context = stream_context_create([
        "http" => [
            "header" => "Authorization: Basic $auth"
        ]
    ]);
    $homepage = file_get_contents($imgUrl, false, $context);
    if ($homepage) {
        file_put_contents($pathSave, $homepage);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

щас выдаёться ошибка 403, что озночает что нет доступа к этой функций, хотя ничего не поменялось

если этот же URl: https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/download/ece9dd8a-d8c7-416c-93ec-aefc31e9e364

открыть в браузере и ввести логин и пароль, то всё нормально - скачиваеться

в чем может быть проблема?
служба поддержки не отвечает на вопросы по API

Comment: Удается ли скачать картинку также через через cURL?

Comment: Через curl у меня не получалось, поэтому и сделал на file_get_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал этот же код на curl, и сработало:

```
public function saveImgMoySklad($imgUrl, $pathSave, $username, $password) {


    $fp = fopen($pathSave, 'w+');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $imgUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    fclose($fp);

    return $result ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это происходит потому что в браузере происходит редирект. При запросе

```
curl -X GET   https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/download/YOUR_UUID_OF_IMAGE   -H 'Authorization: Basic ENTER_YOUR'   -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --verbose
```

будет получен ответ, в которой есть строчка на скачивание отображения (и соответствующий статус)

```
Location: https://storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com:8080/v1/SOME_STUFF.jpg
```

Вопрос в том, почему раньше у Вас все работало корректно, а потом перестало.
Есть [документация](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) по печати этикеток и ценников, где можно посмотреть как можно скачать Изображение.

Comment: Получаеться что если сделать через curl, то должно работать?

Comment: ссылка на документацию для этикетки и ценники, а мне нужно картинка товара

Comment: При скачивании картинки приходит также заголовок Location